# Good sophisticated linq to sql sample?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am looking for a more sophisticated way of using Linq to SQL. I am leaning L2Q but I am only seeing simple examples of business objects and simple CRUD operations in them.

Any sample application that includes these:

1- Business objects which get their data from more than 1 table and from many to many tables.

2- Keeping track of  data changes and automatically be able to  make changes to more than one table in a simple operation. An intelligent SubmitChanges? (don't know if this possible - right now I write my own stored procs to do all the work plus I am desiging my database in a way so my use of Linq to SQL is easier!)

3- Good use of relationships between tables. It should be more than just dragging tables into the designer.

4- Transactions

5- disconnected data. Use in ASP.NET.

6- N-Tier architecture

7- Basically, more sophisticated use of LINQ to SQL and learning good design patterns

8- Skip Linq to SQL and move to Linq to Entities?

I feel I am not taking good advantage of Linq and it's just giving me nice intellisense and easier queries and I feel it has a lot more to offer but not sure what and how.
I am looking for real life sophisticated samples which can be a good source for learning above from what books and tutorials provide.

Anything on CodePlex? Google code... etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scott Gutherie did a 9 part series on his blog that might be of interest to you

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Comment: I would really be missing good design patterns here. (ie. a good DAL and BLL)

Comment: Thanks.. I was aware of these but I am looking for something more sophisticated

Answer (score 3):

Here's two other sources with broad content:

[This](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL.ashx) website is a wiki with a ton of information.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) is a well-organized MSDN reference with hundreds of code samples.

Comment: Thanks. Looking for something more sophisticated. Not looking for general LINQ info.